# how to access other classes in flash builder

Tags: flash, builder

I never used flash develop before but I do have a good understanding of how flash makes its libraries of sorts. Though I can not figure out where or how to include things so they work right. This project is dead and I'm try to recreated the environment. I'm stuck on the pathing here. I figure an image is the best way to show this.

[image]

I can make things work by copy multiple references of the com but I'd rather set this up so the environment know where things are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getting the error because your path/folders setup is wrong.

in `src` you've made a folder with one long name:

```
"com.infrasafe.imonitor.assets"
```

**Solution:**

The dot/period `.` in path names means `this is a sub-folder`,
so basically it's a *directory within another directory*.

Inside `src` create a new sub-folder called `com`, and inside there put a new folder called `infrasafe`, which itself holds a new folder called `imonitor`, and that one finally contains a new folder called `assets` where now the `.as` files like `GraphicsIconStore.as` are placed.

Correct folder names/structure leading to AS files:

`src` ➜ `com` ➜ `infrasafe` ➜ `imonitor` ➜ `assets` ➜ `GraphicsIconStore.as` 
*(ie: the AS file is located inside the `assets` folder)*.